# Is it possible to use English-Hindi converter software in Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex4.6, hindi

I am using Flex4.6 and anmol hindi font. But some are missing in Keymap and it is difficult to type those words.

So, I want to type Hindi in a easy way, as we do in Gmail. So for that I got a software called English to Hindi converter in Indiatyping.com. But don't know how to use that in my application. I tried all most all fonts. But it is difficult to type few words and there are no proper guidelines to type all the alphabets. From a,aa, k,kha, to ka, kaa, jna, jnaa.

Please help me. Tired by searching in google. But didn't get any proper solution.